# Find continuous occurrence of a string in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  log_alerts 
0         no   
1        yes    
2        yes   
3         no    
4        yes   
5        yes
6        yes
7        yes
```

I am trying to find the continuous yes occuring in the log_alerts column and on third time, the code should prompt.

Expected output:

```
  log_alerts    message
0         no   none
1        yes   none
2        yes   none
3         no   none
4        yes   none
5        yes   none
6        yes   continuity found
7        yes   Review again
```

How can I achieve this?

Can it be done using pandas library?

Comment: What happens if `7       yes` ?

Comment: @jezrael, Then it should also give the same prompt as "review".

Comment: @jezrael, input for last row as in??

Comment: Yes, it is correct now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need:

- first distinguish groups by compare [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed columns with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)
- filter only `yes` rows
- get counts per groups by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for `Series` with same index as original `DataFrame`
- last create new column by [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

---

```
a = df['log_alerts'].ne(df['log_alerts'].shift()).cumsum()
a = a[df['log_alerts'] == 'yes']
counts = a.groupby(a).cumcount().reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
print (counts)
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    0
5    1
6    2
7    3
dtype: int64
```

---

```
masks = [counts == 2, counts > 2]
df['message'] = np.select(masks, ['continuity found','Review again'], default=None)
print (df)
  log_alerts           message
0         no              None
1        yes              None
2        yes              None
3         no              None
4        yes              None
5        yes              None
6        yes  continuity found
7        yes      Review again
```

**Details**:

```
print (type(a))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print (a)
1    2
2    2
4    4
5    4
6    4
7    4
Name: log_alerts, dtype: int32
```

Comment: it is giving an attribute error as "AttributeError: Cannot access attribute 'index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method"

Comment: I have used cumcount.

Comment: @Dheeraj - `Details` was added to answer.